# Sort products by Sales & Stock Status : WooCommerce Catalog

Tags: woocommerce

Please refer to this article here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70472545/query-products-and-order-by-date-and-stocks-status-in-woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com)

CODE

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'sort_by_stock_status_and_date', 999 );
function sort_by_stock_status_and_date( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) return;

    $query->set( 'meta_key', '_stock_status' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', array( 'meta_value' => 'ASC', 'date' => 'DESC' )  );
}
```

I want to sort the products by giving first priority to Sales and second to meta_key = _stock_status

What will it achieve? Products will be ordered by popularity and only instock products will appear on the top.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'sort_by_stock_status_and_date', 999 );
function sort_by_stock_status_and_date( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) return;

    $query->set( 'meta_key', '_stock_status' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', array( 'meta_value' => 'ASC', 'date' => 'DESC' )  );
}
```

I also tried:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'sort_by_stock_status_and_date', 999 );
function sort_by_stock_status_and_date( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) return;

    $query->set( 'meta_key', '_stock_status' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', array( 'meta_value' => 'ASC', 'popularity' => 'DESC' )  );
}
```

Comment: you havent define total_sales meta key and order by it meta_value_num

Comment: can you please give me the code?